# Image to 0,1 text

Tags: python, image, text, binary, python-imaging-library

I need to convert an image to text or image that consists of only 0 and 1. Is there any way to do this programmatically, preferably on Python?

Here is my try:

**Step 1:** Open the image:

```
from PIL import Image
srcImage = Image.open("src.jpg")
```

[image]

**Step 2:** Greyscale the image:

```
grayImage = srcImage.convert('L')
```

[image]

**Step 3:** Binarize the image:

```
binarizedImage = grayImage.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1')
```

[image]

Now, I am stuck converting black points to 1, and white points to 0 and save this to text file with image height converted to lines (in this example: 174 pixels to 174 lines) and image width converted to text length (in this example: 310 pixels to 310 character length) or larger image with 0 instead of white points and 1 instead of black points.

Solution to both cases would have been appreciated a lot.

Full binarization code (modified version of the PIL way of [binarizing](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-convert-grayscale-image-to-binary-image-using-python)):

```
from PIL import Image
srcImage = Image.open("src.jpg")
grayImage = srcImage.convert('L')
binarizedImage = grayImage.point(lambda x: 0 if x<128 else 255, '1')
binarizedImage.save("binarized.png")
```

Comment: You can transform your image from a `PIL.Image` to a `numpy.array` using `numpy.array(image)` and then applying your lambda using [apply_over_axes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.apply_over_axes.html) (If you want to retransform it into an image, [here's a nice way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10967471/8583681)) (If this helped you, i can make an answer to the post out of this comment)

Comment: Thanks, I will check this to ensure if this works. I will be glad if you posted it as answer, so that I can accept to make it easier for others to find the solution for similar conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy library for this

```
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage import zoom
import numpy as np
srcImage = Image.open("src.jpg")
grayImage = col.convert('L')
array = np.array(grayImage)
array = zoom(array, 310/174)
np.savetxt("binarized.txt", array<128, fmt="%d")
```

there `np.array` convert PIL Image to numpy array format, zoom interpolate array with given scale, `array < 128` create binary array and `fmt="%d"` set that result will be saved as integer

Comment: you can add the `Image.fromarray()` solution if he wants an image instead of a `.txt`

Comment: But method to get binary image is in question.

Comment: +1, it works, but white points are indicated as 1, whereas black are 0. I can complement them anyway. What about the second part - saving image as larger 0 and 1 image?

Comment: I forgot about interpolation. I edited response and add this steep. You should provide valid scalar. 

Also reverse `array > 128` to `array < 128`  (I`m not sure if you need `<` or `<=`)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now there is no need to complement. :)

Comment: OK, I found a solution to convert text to image file here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760402/converting-a-txt-file-to-an-image-in-python