# Finding an algorithm to split text evenly inside an image with Pillow/Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to convert text into an image with pillow and python, with the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29775654/13354617) + I added some lines to make the text split into columns in order to make a square image because the code of the answer shows the text in just one tall column.
here's an example output of a large text file(it's just a thumbnail because the original image is large): [image: current result]

you can see in the bottom right that there's empty space, that happens because the text lines are not split evenly, I tried everything, I hope someone can help me fix it.

here's how I want it to look: (without the empty space in the bottom right)[image: best result] to do this, the script must split the lines evenly between the columns.

THANK YOU

here's the code

```
import PIL, math, os
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ImageFont
import PIL.ImageOps
import PIL.ImageDraw

def text_image(text_path, font_path=None):
    with open(text_path) as text_file:
        lines = tuple(l.rstrip() for l in text_file.readlines())

    large_font = 15
    font_path = font_path or 'font.ttf'
    try:
        font = PIL.ImageFont.truetype(font_path, size=large_font)
    except IOError:
        font = PIL.ImageFont.load_default()
        print('Could not use chosen font. Using default.')

    pt2px = lambda pt: int(round(pt * 96.0 / 72))
    max_width_line = max(lines, key=lambda s: font.getsize(s)[0])

    test_string = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    max_height = pt2px(font.getsize(test_string)[1])
    max_width = pt2px(font.getsize(max_width_line)[0])
    mw = font.getsize(max_width_line)[0]
    mh = font.getsize(max_width_line)[1]
    height = max_height * len(lines)
    width = int(round(max_width + 40))
    
    block = int(mw/mh)
    squareBlock = int(math.sqrt(len(lines)/(mw/mh))) + 1
    
    squareImageSize = block * squareBlock * block
    
    image = PIL.Image.new('L', (squareImageSize, squareImageSize), color=PIXEL_OFF)
    draw = PIL.ImageDraw.Draw(image)
    
    vertical_position = 20
    horizontal_position = 20
    line_spacing = int(round(max_height * 0.8))
    i = 0
    for e, line in enumerate(lines):
        draw.text((horizontal_position, vertical_position),
                  line, fill=PIXEL_ON, font=font)
        vertical_position += line_spacing
        
        if e % block == 0 and not e==0:
            i+=1
        if i == squareBlock:
            i = 0
            horizontal_position += mw - 20
            vertical_position = 20

    a, b, c, d = PIL.ImageOps.invert(image).getbbox()
    image = image.crop((0,0,c+20,d+20))
    
    return image
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you are actually trying to do. Nor what the problem is. And you can share proper resolution images - up to 2MB- or use Dropbox or Google Drive or similar.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thank you, I edited the question. I added the result that I want to see

Comment: Sorry, I still see a low resolution input image and still have no idea what you are hoping to do.