# Is there an option to save Python files to images with Pycharm?

Tags: python, syntax, pycharm, export

I have a project I finished, and one requirement is adding all of the code to a Word Document, doing it manually will take hours since I have multiple Python files, each with at least 200 lines.

Is there a way to export them (with the syntax highlighting) to images so I can do it quickly, and be able to add them to the Word Document?

Comment: You can try taking a screenshot to keep the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Yes I know but I'm trying to avoid doing so, because as I said doing it manually will take hours since I have multiple Python files, each with at least 200 lines

Comment: Does it have to be saved as words in the word document.

Comment: No, it can be photos and I think it's even preferred, but the syntax highlighting is important. (Python syntax)
If the syntax wasn't important I would turn the code into a pdf file and turn that pdf file to images.

Comment: If you take one screenshot of 30 lines in each 3 seconds, in 20 min you can take 400 screenshots containing 12000 lines of code. Is your codebase bigger than that ?

Comment: I cant think of any way to do what you are asking for but to take screenshots of the code and add the photos to the word document

Comment: Windows 7 builtin screenshot application would work perfectly for this.

Comment: I'll try a Visual Studio Code extension someone here recommended, and if that doesn't work I think I'll create an AHK script to scroll and take screenshots.

Comment: If you copy-paste the code programmatically into a wordpad process the syntax highlight information will be retained with the exact colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in pycharm but in Virsual Studio Code, there is and extension called [CodeSnap](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.codesnap), maybe just open your project from vscode then take clean screenshots of your code from there.

Comment: Sounds like this could work, I'll give it a try and come back!

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, if you take one screenshot of 30 lines in each 3 seconds, in 20 min you can take 400 screenshots containing 12000 lines of code, which might be enough for many projects .

But if you really want to automate it, one idea can be to write a python file that read the files in your project recursively and at each fixed number of lines write the content to a .txt file with a name like file_n.txt, where n is increasing. Then, you convert all the .txt to images programatically using [pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29760402/converting-a-txt-file-to-an-image-in-python).

Comment: I'll try a Visual Studio Code extension someone here recommended, and if that doesn't work I think I'll create an AHK script to scroll and take screenshots.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting small python package to write :) you can even let it pip installable . I can try it in my free time